EOFError : Ran out of Input Error with multiprocessing in Python
I'm trying to write a download manager with the gallery_dl library in python, but I'm having a issue with multiprocessing(for managing multiple download tasks in a web-ui inerface).
When I try to create a new job in the __init__ method of the DownloadTask class, I get a self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent) ... EOFError: Ran out of input error.
I'm guessing this is because multiprocessing is using pickle to serialize the stuff in the child processes, and pickle can't handle the gallery_dl instance, but I have no idea what to do about this.
Is there a way to fix or get around this?
Here's a simplified version of my code:
# DownloadManager.py
from typing import Dict
from DownloadTask import DownloadTask
import uuid
import multiprocessing

class DownloadManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks: Dict[str, DownloadTask] = {}
        self.processes: Dict[str, multiprocessing.Process] = {}

    def add_task(self, url: str) -> str:
        task_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        new_task = DownloadTask(task_id, url)
        self.tasks[task_id] = new_task

        task_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=new_task.start)
        self.processes[task_id] = task_process
        task_process.start()

        return task_id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    downloader = DownloadManager()
    downloader.add_task("https://lexica.art/?q=cats")

# DownloadTask.py
from gallery_dl import job

class DownloadTask:
    def __init__(self, task_id: str, url: str):
        self.task_id = task_id
        self.url = url
        self.job = job.DownloadJob(url)

    def start(self):
        self._download()

    def _download(self):
        self.job.run()

I tried to init the job as None and create it in the start method of the DownloadTask class. But this way I can't access the job later in other methods(which I need to in the pause/resume methods)
# Modified DownloadTask.py
from gallery_dl import job

class DownloadTask:
    def __init__(self, task_id: str, url: str):
        self.task_id = task_id
        self.url = url
        self.job = None  # init as None

    def start(self):
        self.job = job.DownloadJob(self.url) # create the job instance
        self._download()

    def _download(self):
        self.job.run()
    
    def pause(self):
        print(self.job) # this will print None
        # actual pausing code

Note the pause method in DownloadTask is mandatory because I have a extended class for gallery_dl's DownloadJob class for pausing and other modifications. What I need here is to access self.job from the puause method here(if it's possible).

You can try using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor
The following steps provide a way to solve the problem.

Your DownloadManager would submit tasks to the ProcessPoolExecutor
For every task will run within its own process, while the gallery_dl download job would be within each process.

Finally each task is then submitted to the executor.submit()
Here is a code snippet to guide you.
import uuid
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from typing import Dict
from DownloadTask import DownloadTask

class DownloadManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks: Dict[str, DownloadTask] = {}
        self.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor() 

    def add_task(self, url: str) -> str:
        task_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        new_task = DownloadTask(task_id, url)
        self.tasks[task_id] = new_task

        # Submit the task to the ProcessPoolExecutor
        self.executor.submit(new_task.start)

        return task_id

    def shutdown(self):
        # Gracefully shut down the executor, waiting for all tasks to complete
        self.executor.shutdown(wait=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    downloader = DownloadManager()
    # Add multiple tasks for concurrent execution
    downloader.add_task("https://lexica.art/?q=cats")
    downloader.add_task("https://lexica.art/?q=rabbits")

    # shutdowns the executor
    downloader.shutdown()


To pause the task you would have to know what pid(process ID (PID)) is running, and you would have to fall back to the os and  SIGCONT from signal
You can use signal.pause() to put a process into a waiting state until it receives any signal. For your task manager, signal.pause() could be used to make the current process wait until a signal (like SIGCONT) is received.
while

signal.SIGCONT Continue the process if it is currently stopped

You can use the docs for reference: docs
Here is an example
 def pause(self):
     print(f"Task {self.task_id} is pausing.")
     self.job.pause()  # <- your job 


A paused task implementation..
from DownloadTask import DownloadTask
from time import sleep

class DownloadManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks: Dict[str, DownloadTask] = {}
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()  # using the executor

    def add_task(self, url: str) -> str:
        task_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        new_task = DownloadTask(task_id, url)
        self.tasks[task_id] = new_task

        # Submit the task to the ThreadPoolExecutor
        self.executor.submit(new_task.start)

        return task_id

    def pause_task(self, task_id: str):
        # access the task 
        task = self.tasks.get(task_id)
        task.pause()

    def shutdown(self):
        # shutdown the executor
        self.executor.shutdown(wait=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    downloader = DownloadManager()
    # Add multiple tasks for concurrent execution
    task_id = downloader.add_task("https://lexica.art/?q=cats")
     
    # place a sleep on the pause
    sleep(3)
    downloader.pause_task(task_id)

    # Shutdown the executor
    downloader.shutdown()


Please check the question again since i also tried this but will cause other issues

@LaurenceY apologies how about using Pool, is it something you would love to try?

Yes please as long as it can fix my issue

Thank you for the answer. Can you please add a pause_task function to show me how to pause a task? I just need to access the running process from the pause method, not the actual pausing code

ok no problem , I have done that for you

Thank you very, very much for the answer, but this approach is not ideal for me. I'm sorry for not clearing this up earlier, but I have a pause method built in the pause method of DownloadTask class, the only thing I need to is accessing the correct job instance from the pause method. Is this possible?

I have updated the code. I believe this should solve your problem, it is important to note that you can look at the docs also for further help.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
